# Smart search index issue – Kentico 9

Tags: search, kentico

Our team of developers have been having an ongoing issue with smart search functionality not working as expected in our PROD website. UAT site works as expected. We use Kentico 9 CMS.

**Example:**
We have created a page in Kentico and added some information to the smart search field. We followed the same process in UAT and PROD but only UAT comes back with search results when you use this functionality on the website.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8117g.jpg)

Below - search results in UAT – PROD does not come back with anything related:

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viQXK.jpg)

**What we have done so far to try and solve the issue:**

•   We noticed the PROD site needed an index status rebuild. We processed the rebuild but it did not solve the problem. After a while, it requested another rebuild. 
[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3nW7.jpg)

•   PROD site is linked to Azure Portal and is scaled out to a minimum of 2 instances while UAT is scaled out to only 1 instance. We tried to reproduce the same issue in UAT (where we can debug it) by increasing its number of instances to 2. It did not make any difference; the search functionality still works fine in UAT but not in PROD.

•   We saved scheduled task – Execute search tasks again to make sure this is running as expected. The scheduled task is running fine but It did not help solving the problem. 
[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFyho.jpg)

Does anybody have any idea or experienced the same or similar issue before?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that your scheduled task is run on each web farm server individually.
Take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/configuring-kentico/setting-up-search-on-your-website) (Check the Tip: Executing search tasks via the scheduler on a web farm). Anyway to me it looks like more a web farm synchronization issue than issue with smart search

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I had a look at the documentation. It seems like a good approach, but before applying any of this, could you please clarify the following?
1. Prod site is hosted in Azure. I assume the server names change over time, which makes it difficult to name it in Kentico as it is mutable. Could you please confirm if this is of any concern? Any ideas on how to tackle this issue?
2. The Prod site is set up to auto-scale (scale out) in Azure. Its instances can vary between a minimum of 2 and a maximum of 5. Do you have any suggestion on how to apply it in Kentico?